# Removing file extension AND file name from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've found several articles on how to remove the file extension using mod rewrite in the .htaccess script, but ideally I'd like to remove both the extension **and** the file name.

For instance, wearedeja.com/index.html should display wearedeja.com

Obviously sites like apple.com can do this, so it has to be possible, even if complicated.

I've searched and searched both on stack overflow and off, and can't seem to find more than removing extensions. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: you don't have to do anything for index.php(html) just give the directory path only: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: does this work with html files as well? I'm using no php at all currently. I know I can stealth forward to get the same effect, but I really don't want to do that

Comment: yes by default appache will use index.html as the directory index

Comment: Do not use `/index.html` inside the links to home page in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as your server uses nginx as a server, and not apache:

i think this should work:

```
index index.html index.php;
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

That should be added to your nginx config

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*?/?)index\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Comment: I don't speak much php, but just to clarify any filename after DirectoryIndex in this syntax is the pages that will be hidden from the URL? Trying this soon!

Comment: @fuccboi this isn't php, it's mod_rewrite and you add these to your htaccess file. Anything after `DirectoryIndex` is the file that apache will look for when the request is for a *directory*. If none of those files are found, apache will (by default) list the *contents* of the directory